# Error al reducir tamaño/resolución de images con imageField de Django

Tags: python, django

Las imágenes subidas al servidor pesan mucho. Por este motivo, trato de comprimir las imágenes para que se reduzcan pero me sigue guardando con la misma resolución y tamaño.
**Al subir la imagen, devuelve el siguiente error:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Model:**

```
class ImageInstallation(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Título',max_length=50,null=True, blank=True)
    installation = models.ForeignKey(Installation, related_name="installation_image",on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)
    image_imageInstallation = models.ImageField(upload_to='img/installations/')
    datetime = models.DateField ('FechaImagen',null=True, blank=True)
    mainPicture = models.BooleanField('Imagen principal', default=False, null=True, blank=True)
    pictureDescription = models.TextField('Descripción de la imagen', null=True,blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       instance = super(ImageInstallation, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
       image = Image.open(instance.image_imageInstallation.path)
       image.save(instance.image_imageInstallation.path,quality=20,optimize=True)
       return instance

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Imagen instalación'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Imagen de instalaciones'
        ordering = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.image_imageInstallation)
```

Comment: Por favor, pon el error _como texto_ (incluso es mejor si escribes el error en el título). Es para mejor legibilidad (además que no todos podrán ver tal imagen por restricciones existentes, por ejemplo).

Answer (score 0):

El método `save` no retorna ningun valor. Toda referencia a `instance` realmente intentan hacer referencia al propio objeto, es decir, a `self`.

```py
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super(ImageInstallation, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
       image = Image.open(self.image_imageInstallation.path)
       image.save(self.image_imageInstallation.path,quality=20,optimize=True)
```

Comment: Gracias, pero el nombre instance no está definido en tu código. ¿No es así? Un saludo.

Comment: Solucionado. El super es guardado en instance. Y funciona perfecto. Muchas gracias.